# for_each algorithm:error C2672: 'for_each': no matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++

Exercises on c++ primer：write a function that takes a string and return a bool indicating whether the string has five charcaters or more.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

void elimDups(vector<string>& words)
{
    sort(words.begin(), words.end());
    auto end_unique = unique(words.begin(), words.end());
    words.erase(end_unique, words.end());
}

string make_plural(string::size_type count, string str, string plur)
{
    return count > 1 ? str + plur : str;
}

bool check_size(const string& s, vector<string>::size_type sz)
{
    return s.size() > sz;
}

void biggies(vector<string>& words, vector<string>::size_type sz)
{
    elimDups(words);
    stable_sort(words.begin(), words.end(),
        [](const string& a, const string& b) -> bool { return a.size() < b.size(); });

    auto wc = find_if(words.cbegin(), words.cend(), bind(check_size, _1, sz));
    auto count = words.end() - wc;
    cout << count << " " << make_plural(count, "word", "s") << " of length " << sz << " or longer" << endl;
    for_each(wc, words.end(), [](string& s)-> void {cout << s << endl; });
}

int main()
{
    istringstream os("the quick red fox jumps over the slow red turtle");
    string word;
    vector<string> svec;
    while (os >> word)
        svec.push_back(word);
    biggies(svec, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Report the following error：error C2672: 'for_each': no matching overloaded function found.
What is wrong with this code?Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the call to:

```cpp
for_each(wc, words.cend(), [](const string& s)-> void {cout << s << endl; });
```

Explanation:

You pass cbegin and cend to `find_if`, meaning it returns a const iterator. So you also need to pass a const end iterator to for_each, and expect the lambda parameter as a const reference.